# css center a fixed div with no overflow

Tags: css

I'm trying to center a `fixed` div on the top of a page with no `overflow`.

I can't seem to get the overflow working properly

### [Here's what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/yqzdp/)

As you can see, I don't want the entire top to be white, just the part that's not `inner`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: this is unclear, what are you trying to do exactly? you're specifying you want "the part that's not `inner`" to be white, yet you declared a white background for `inner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want, only "#inner" to be white, change your CSS to :

```
#inner {      
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:white;
}
```

if you want only #inner to be yellow, then :

CSS

```
#inner {      
    background-color:white;
}
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="inner"><span class="yellow" >Loading</span></div>
```

Comment: @Eliran Malka , the current code is wrong, "display" keyword is missing.

Comment: @xFortyFourx: ooh, i missed the display keyword. Thanks, will accept when able